# locationtech simplified geometry - distance tolerance units

Tags: java, jts-topology-suite

When using `org.locationtech.jts.simplify`, there is a parameter called **distanceTolerance**. What are the units in for this parameter?  For example, feet, meters, km, etc. I'm not sure if this is relavent, but I am using this with a geopackage from gadm.org. The [documentation](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/simplify/TopologyPreservingSimplifier.html) defines this as,

> Sets the distance tolerance for the simplification.

and

> The simplification uses a maximum-distance difference algorithm similar to the Douglas-Peucker algorithm.

Comment: All units are assumed to be CRS units.

Answer (score 0):

JTS always works in the units of the dataset you are using.